# how to reuse a form and jquery ajax call in multiple sections of a document?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working on jquery dialog email attachment. I created a separate form to upload file that uses formdata object. I want to reuse the form and its related ajax call in different dialogs in the same php page(reason: need email attachment functionality in other dialogs). How can i achieve this?

Jquery Ajax call:

```
  $('#attchform').submit(function(event) {
     $.ajax({
         url: 'uploadfile.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: new FormData(this),
         processData: false,
         contentType: false,
         success: function(data) {
             document.getElementById("fileToUpload").disabled = true;
             $("#loadimg").html(data);
         }
     });
     event.preventDefault();
 });
```

Html form:

```
<form id="attchform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Attach" name="submit">
</form> 
<div id="loadimg"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function and call any where in the same page:

```
function UploadFile(){ 
   $.ajax({
     url: 'uploadfile.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: new FormData(this),
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     success: function(data) {
         document.getElementById("fileToUpload").disabled = true;
         $("#loadimg").html(data);
     }
  });
}



$('#attchform').submit(function(event) {
    UploadFile();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```